# Meaning of "has come to"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In text, all-caps **has come to** be understood as 'shouting'.

What's the meaning of **has come to**?

I'm pretty sure it means *can* in this contexts. If so, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Come*** [to VERB] is closely related to *be**come***: both designate gradual arrival at an enduring state. *Become* is used with nominal or adjectival complements, *come* is used with infinitival complements—usually stative verbs, or telic verbs which can be 'recategorized' as stative.

> I used to dislike him, but I have ***become fond*** of him.
>   I used to dislike him, but I have ***come to love*** him.

All-caps was common in the days of teletypes and early computers; for instance, I can remember a time when speeches were always typed in caps because that's the only sort of characters that teleprompters could display. Over time, however, as computers **became** capable of more complex display, all-caps was deprecated: it **became** a sign of rudeness—it **came** to be understood as 'shouting'.

Answer (score 1):

has come to [be understood as, seen as, etc. and has come to [mean, signify]

means: has evolved historically to mean or has evolved over a period of time to mean.